# How to deal with nested promises in javascript angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise

Function 2 is using Function 1 return while Function 3 uses both returns, how to do cleanly ?
Function 3 is only returning me undefined values right nom.

Here are my 3 functions.

**Function1**

```
$scope.nombreCompetencesATraiter = function(){
var nbr = 0;
        notesService.getNotesByCollaborateurId($scope.idCollaborateurSelectionne).then(function(data){
            $scope.myNotes = data;
            angular.forEach($scope.myNotes, function(valueNote, keyNote) {
                if ((valueNote.status === "EN_ATTENTE_DE_VALIDATION") || (valueNote.status === "EN_ATTENTE_DE_SUPPRESSION")){
                    nbr++;
                }
            })
            console.log(nbr);
            return nbr;
        })
    }
```

**Function 2**

```
$scope.affinerConfigBoutonsCompetences = function() {
        nbCompetenceATraiter = $scope.nombreCompetencesATraiter();
        if (nbCompetenceATraiter == 0){
            $scope.radioModelFilterToutesLesCompetences = true;
            $scope.radioModelFilterCompetencesAValider = false;
        }
        else{
            $scope.radioModelFilterCompetencesAValider = true;
            $scope.radioModelFilterToutesLesCompetences = false;
        }
    }
```

**Function 3**

```
$scope.affinerConfigBoutonsCompetencesThen = function(){
        $q.all([$scope.nombreCompetencesATraiter(), $scope.affinerConfigBoutonsCompetences()]).then(function(value) {
            console.log(value[0]);
            console.log(value[1]);
        })
    }
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Your function 2 should take the `nbCompetenceATraiter` as a parameter. Writing function 3 correctly should be trivial then. Whether you need an additional function that does what your current function 2 does (i.e. call function 1 and then set the scope values) only you can decide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some mistakes which Luillyfe mentioned, and in general here is the most concise way to resolve that dependency.

```
var f1 = () => new Promise( resolve => resolve('value1'));
var f2 = ( value1 ) => new Promise( resolve => resolve('value2'));
var f3 = ( value1, value2 ) => new Promise( resolve => resolve('done'));

f1()
    .then( value1 => Promise.all([ value1, f2( value1 ) ]) )
    .then( ([ value1, value2 ]) => f3( value1, value2 ))
```

It's handy to use `Promise.all` with non-Promise values, it will just pass them straight through to `then`.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys, I'll try some more tomorrow since my workday is over.

Answer (score 0):

**Function 1** missing return statement before calling `noteService`

```
$scope.nombreCompetencesATraiter = function() {
var nbr = 0;
  return notesService.getNotesByCollaborateurId($scope.idCollaborateurSelectionne)
    .then(function(data) {
      $scope.myNotes = data;
      angular.forEach($scope.myNotes, function(valueNote, keyNote) {
        if ((valueNote.status === "EN_ATTENTE_DE_VALIDATION") || (valueNote.status === "EN_ATTENTE_DE_SUPPRESSION")) {
          nbr++;
        }
      })
      console.log(nbr);
      return nbr;
  })
}
```

**Function 2**

```
$scope.affinerConfigBoutonsCompetences = function() {
  return $scope.nombreCompetencesATraiter().then(function (value) {
    nbCompetenceATraiter = value;
    if (nbCompetenceATraiter == 0) {
      $scope.radioModelFilterToutesLesCompetences = true;
      $scope.radioModelFilterCompetencesAValider = false;
    } else {
      $scope.radioModelFilterCompetencesAValider = true;
      $scope.radioModelFilterToutesLesCompetences = false;
    }
    return nbCompetenceATraiter // value you want to return
  });
}
```

**Function 3**

```
$scope.affinerConfigBoutonsCompetencesThen = function(){
    $q.all([$scope.nombreCompetencesATraiter(), $scope.affinerConfigBoutonsCompetences()]).then(function(value) {
        console.log(value[0]);
        console.log(value[1]);
    })
}
```

Let now how that works!

Comment: Thanks a lot guys, I'll try some more tomorrow since my workday is over.